# Stopping an intent from a thread and starting a new intent :Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

I've tried all weekend to find the answer to this, but I'm lost.  I may have programmed myself into a hole, and need to do something different.

Imagine that my game launches into the main activity (the intro screen),
then if the player wishes to view the whole continent a intent starts the Continent View Activity.  If the player wishes to view the local city, then an intent starts the city view activity.

I can do this with buttons on the main intro screen, but I want the player to be able to select a the City Location on the Continent View.  The result is to stop the intent for the Continent View and then trigger the activity for the City View.

The problem is, I don't seem to be able to call finish from the Thread (SurfaceView) that is drawing Continent View.

I don't really want to make the Continent Map out of Buttons if I can help it.  For now, the Continent View is made of .PNG cells.

Is my whole approach wrong?

Comment: My advice: Don't have so many different Activities doing similar things! You can have just one Activity and just switch the views within that Activity.

Comment: I want to eventually share the Continent Map as a multiplayer game, so I thought it would be better to have multiple activities. Also, I'm new here, but I thought each screen should be a seperate Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `post()` on your `SurfaceView` with a `Runnable` that calls `finish()`.

Comment: both are terrific suggestions, but I already implemented something that works. It seems the line "((Activity) getContext()).finish();" will stop the Activity from anywhere. I'm sure there are other ways. I'll keep experimenting, but I'm moving on for now.